How to get XCode to use relative path
I built a MacOS terminal program, lets call this XCode Project (2), that uses files from another XCode Project (1). I did this by adding in those files from XCode Project (1) in the Compile Sources section of Build Phases of XCode Project (2).
This works fine and I believe this is the correct way to set this up given the information out there.
My Project directories are in the Apple iCloud.
I have a second machine and I'm trying to read in those files in from the iCloud into XCode. XCode Project (1) compiles fine because it doesn't have any of those dependencies described above. However I run into issues with XCode Project (2).
The problem is that the username for my original machine is not the same username for my second machine.
So when it attempts to compile I'll get an error like:
error: Build input file cannot be found: '/Users/USERNAME_ON_MACHINE1/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Code/Fractal/Fractal MacOS/Fractal MacOS-Bridging-Header.h'. Did you forget to declare this file as an output of a script phase or custom build rule which produces it? (in target 'Fractal Dive' from project 'Fractal Dive')

Where USERNAME_ON_MACHINE1 is my username. This would probably work if I could change that to be relative directory name instead of the actual directory name so instead of:
/Users/USERNAME_ON_MACHINE1/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Code/Fractal/Fractal MacOS/Fractal MacOS-Bridging-Header.h

It could read:
../../Code/Fractal/Fractal MacOS/Fractal MacOS-Bridging-Header.h

That might work. But I am not sure, nor sure how I could setup XCode to try this out.
If someone has some good advice for me on this issue I'd appreciate it.

If you have multiple Xcode Projects that are related, you should probably be using an Xcode Workspace to bind them together.  This way you can define the dependencies between the projects, which will allow the dep project to build before the other project. See the Xcode docs.

When you add a file to a project, the way it is referenced by the project can be set by selecting the file in the Project Navigator and switching to the File Inspector. There are various forms of relative addressing that you can choose from. One of these will likely work fine for you.

